Remove style imports from Angular project
Angular Material installed in project.
When I open browser console, there tons of Material styles, thousands of them.
Browser console
Material version: "^17.1.2",
Angular version: "^17.1.1",
This happened after update Angular to 17 version.

this look normal to me, it look like the stylesheets for Angular Material


There are thousands of stylesheets, so browser even lagging, each action in console are like 2-3 seconds. Moreover, they are doubled, as you can see. Half of styles are overwritten 2) My question is - how to remove all that styles? It were perfect before Angular update.


Anyone here? Tried to explaine question above.
